# Function triggering early

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to attempt to call back a value from a function, however, the call back is always undefined because the jQuery Date Picker never has a chance to set the var sdate, thus alerts me that it is undefined. I realy need your help and can't seem to get passed this problem.

```
var sdate
function test() {


    select_date()
    alert(sdate)

    }


  function select_date() {

    $('#dd').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: 'black'
        },
        title: "title",
        height: 265,
        width: 235,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false

    }); //end of dialog

    var x
    $('#d1').datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            sdate = $(this).val();
            $("#dd").dialog("close");
        }
    });
    return sdate

}
```

Comment: `sdate` is actually `undefined` at the time you do `alert(sdate)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does this do for you?

```
$('#d1').datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
           sdate = $(this).val(); 
          //set value to the global variable (although not the best approach)
            $("#dd").dialog("close");
        }
 });
```

Comment: the sdate sets just fine, however, id like to check the value of the sdate in the function test, if its null { do something } if its not { do something else }

Comment: @JasonKelly, why did you mark this as an answer if it is not what you wanted?

Comment: @Alexander: I suspect it's because he has updated the code in the (vague) question based on what I was trying to say here. lol..

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting `sdate` at all. I think perhaps you meant to do `sdate = select_date();`?

Comment: That is what I thought too. But even `x` is `undefined` since it is set only within the `onSelect` event callback.

Comment: I've modified the typo. The real issue is that the alert box in the function test fires early before select_date gets a chance to set the sdate variable

Comment: @JasonKelly: Whatever that function returns it never being used by your `alert` and also never set to - eg: There is no place where do you `sdate = xValue`. What you should try is `alert(select_date)`.