# calling a functions value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, javascript-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function triggering early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201816/function-triggering-early)

I have whipped up this code, but why on earth would it be alerting me that its undefined even though I have never even got a chance to click on and select a date from the UI date picker when I call the function test()?

Doesn't seem to make sense with me?

```
var sdate

function test() {
    alert(select_date())
}

function select_date() {
    $('#dd').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: 'black'
        },
        title: "title",
        height: 265,
        width: 235,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false
    }); //end of dialog

    $('#d1').datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            sdate = $(this).val();
            $("#dd").dialog("close");
        }
    });
    return sdate
}​
```

Comment: OK, in order to help, we need to know three things: the code, what it's supposed to do, and what it's actually doing. You've only provided the first one of those, so you're not likely to get an answer.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'm not having any problems with it.

Comment: Also, cleaning up your code will make it easier for people to help you, not to mention easier for you to maintain.

Comment: The function test() will among some other things, check wether or not the function select_date() will return anything (depending on if the user selects a date or closes the window) Browser version is ie 7

Comment: `return sdate` runs before the user interacts with the dialog due to how javascript works.

Comment: How would you fix that Kevin B? Im still quite new to this stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSelect` is an event callback, you are trying to return a value before it knows what to do. it's not going to be possible to have your `test()` return the value, because it comes later.

you should do your alert or whatever logic from within the event callback:

```
$('#d1').datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        sdate = $(this).val();
        $("#dd").dialog("close");
        alert(sdate);
        // or your own function
        someOtherTest(sdate);
    }
});
```

-

```
function someOtherTest(date) {
    alert(date);
}
```

Comment: Or you can return deferred objects. They simplify code that needs to be run later, like after an async call: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/