# Calling back a functions value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, javascript-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function triggering early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201816/function-triggering-early)
>   [calling a functions value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202188/calling-a-functions-value)

I need some help.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure this out. I've had my head wrapped around it only to no avail.

I'd like to setup two functions.

1. function: `select_date()` to interact with the user to select a date from the jQuery Date picker. If the dialog is closed then return as null.
2. Then a second function: `test()` to check whether or not a date was `picked/selected`.

Here's my dilemma, when the function `test()` is executed, an alert box pops up and says `"undefined"` which means, I never get to select a date and it always being `"undefined"`

I dont see what I am doing wrong here and everything seems logical to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function select_date() {
    var sdate

        $('#dd').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.5,
                background: 'black'
            },
            title: "title",
            height: 265,
            width: 235,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false
        });
        $('#d1').datepicker({
            onSelect: function () {
                $("#dd").dialog("close");
            }
        });
        return sdate
    }

    function test() {
    var x = select_date()

    alert(x)

    }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #d1 {font-size:64%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dd">
<div id="d1">
</div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:test()">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So where are you setting the value of `sdate` then, it does'nt set itself ???

Comment: Where is `sdate` getting set?

Comment: how is it logical, in ur select_date(), u declare sdate and do some nonrelated operation and return sdate, it is obviously undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the way JavaScript works... `select_date()` returns immediately because `.dialog()` and `.datepicker()` are asynchronous methods. `return sdate` is called before anything has even happened.  The right way to do it would be to use callback methods from `onSelect()`

```
function select_date(callback) {
  $('#dd').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: 'black'
        },
        title: "title",
        height: 265,
        width: 235,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false
    });
    $('#d1').datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            $("#dd").dialog("close");
            callback($(this).datepicker('getDate'));
        }
    });
}

function test() {
  select_date(function(selected_date) { alert(selected_date); });
}
```

The only issue with this is that the callback will not be called if no date is selected and the dialog is closed.  You could add an event listener for that on the dialog and make it call `callback` with a `null/undefined` value, but that's up to you.

Comment: Updated using the correct method to get the date. Thanks.  Though `this` in that context is the input field, see the docs http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect

Comment: Wow! I am very intrigued and impressed by this. Thank you so very much for the code and for the awesome help Brendan. Cheers, Jay